# How to run gevent pool for "For Loop"?

Tags: python, gevent

```
for row in data:
                data2 = collections.OrderedDict()
                data2["ID"] = row[0]
                data2["Bank Reconciliation Status"] = row[1]
                data2["Date"] = row[2]
                data2["Branch"] = row[3]
                data2["Student"] = row[4]
                data2["Amount"] = row[5]
                data2["Type"] = row[6]
                data2["Remark"] = row[7]
                data2["Attachment"] = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + ThumbnailEngine(row[8]) + "\">"
                brecon.append(data2)
return json.jsonify({"data": brecon})
```

May I know how do I set up gevent pool for the For Loop above? I need to run as many concurrent requests as possible for the thumbnails downloaded from 3rd Party API. Thank You.

Comment: it doesn't work this way. If you want to run concurrent `requests` then run concurrent `requests` with `gevent`, not `for`-loop. And when you run  `requests` then directly create `OrderedDict()` and put on list. Only functions created specially for `async` can be use `gevent` - like network connections, reading from file, getting from database - but `for`-loop is not created for this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it worked with the following solution by myself. The thumbnails now load 15x faster in Jquery Datatable:

```
from gevent.pool import Pool
import collections

    def test(data): # data from postgresql query result as args
        
        data2 = collections.OrderedDict()
        data2["ID"] = data[0]
        data2["Bank Reconciliation Status"] = data[1]
        data2["Date"] = data[2]
        data2["Branch"] = data[3]
        data2["Student"] = data[4]
        data2["Amount"] = data[5]
        data2["Type"] = data[6]
        data2["Remark"] = data[7]
        data2["Attachment"] = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + ThumbnailEngine(data[8]) + "\">"
        return data2

p = Pool()
brecon = tuple(p.map(test, data)) # data from postgresql query result

return json.jsonify({"data": brecon})
```